# How to set the width of the input element using Foundation 5 Zurb

Tags: zurb-foundation

Below is the html [JSFiddle - Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/AQGd9/12/)

`<div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 medium-3 large-3 columns">
        <label for="firstName" class="inline">* First Name:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="small-9 medium-9 large-9 columns">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
    </div>
</div>`

The input element spans the entire page width by default. I want to limit the width of the element.

One way to achieve this is by using incomplete rows and adding class end.

See below: [JSFiddle - Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/AQGd9/13/)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-3 medium-3 large-3 columns">
    <label for="firstName" class="inline">* First Name:</label>
</div>
<div class="small-3 medium-3 large-3 end columns">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
</div>
```

Is this the correct way? Or is there any other method to do it.
I am aware that I can use css/modify css but wanted to see if there is any other way to do it using Foundation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way to size input elements.

While there are many ways to do it, wrapping form elements in `column` classes is the recommended method. For example, to produce an input with 50% width, wrap the input in a `large-6 columns end` class.

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns end">
      <label>Input Label
        <input type="text" placeholder="large-12.columns" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```